# Sphinx hiding modules imported in __init__.py

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, numpydoc, autosummary

My package has a structure, similar to the following:

```
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── module1
│   └── submodule1.py
│   └── submodule2.py
├── module2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── _hiden_submodule1.py
│   ├── _hiden_submodule2.py
│   └── _hiden_submodule3.py
```

I have managed to document all of it from the docstrings using sphinx, with the autosummary and recursive option:

```
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _autosummary
   :template: custom-module-template.rst
   :recursive:

   mymodule
```

which gives me very nice toctrees from modules to functions.

However, `_hiden_submodules*.py` functions are imported into the `__init__.py` of module2:

```
from mymodule.module2._hiden_submodules1 import *
from mymodule.module2._hiden_submodules2 import *
from mymodule.module2._hiden_submodules3 import *
```

I would like these functions to appear directly in the documentation as being part of module2, and not part of `module2.hiden_submodules*`. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set

```
autosummary_imported_members = True  # Also documents imports in __init__.py
```

in your `conf.py` file. See [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html).